# Permalink with anchor on home page to single page

Tags: permalinks, homepage

I have question regarding the permalink on my home.php page.
How can I make link in home.php page which goes to certain post - so kind of jump automatically to certain area in my single.php page with 12 post on one page. So it will be kind of permalink with anchor together

Comment: <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#......"></a> ???

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way.

```
<a href="<?php print get_permalink($id_of_the_post_you_want_to_link_to); ?>#......">Link</a>
```

`the_permalink()` makes only sense in a post loop. But `get_permalink()` is accepting a parameter of another post and gives you its permalink.